# Merging of two part files with header as only first line Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

how can i merge two or more part files in hadoop to single file in such a way that merge  output is having entire data but, only one header that is in the 1st line of merge output .

**File 1**

```
column1|column2|column3
20000|newyork|john
30000|sydney|joseph
```

**File n**

```
column1|column2|column3
60000|delhi|mike
30000|sydney|joseph
```

**Merged output should be**

```
column1|column2|column3
20000|newyork|john
30000|sydney|joseph
60000|delhi|mike
30000|sydney|joseph
```

**Is there any easy way using hadoop fs -cat command.. ?**

or by any other method..

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1:

Leaving the headers on is fairly complicated without creating an index or rank, since in Pig a collection of tuples is unsorted.  Here's what a Pig job looks like, using rank and order by to place the header on top.

**header_ranked.pig**

```
HEADER = LOAD 'header.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (b0:int,b1:chararray,b2:chararray,b3:chararray);
H1 = LOAD 'header_test' USING PigStorage('|') AS (c1:chararray,c2:chararray,c3:chararray);
F_H1 = FILTER H1 BY NOT (c1 MATCHES 'column1' AND c2 MATCHES 'column2' AND c3 MATCHES 'column3');
R_H1 = RANK F_H1 by c1 DESC DENSE;
U = UNION R_H1, HEADER;
O = ORDER U by rank_F_H1; 
F = FOREACH O GENERATE c1,c2,c3;

dump F;
```

The two sample files, each containing 2 records and a header line, were placed in a directory called `header_test`.  Additionally, in order for this program to work, I had to create a header file in the following format:

**header.txt**

`0|column1|column2|column3`

Walking through the code, the file containing the headers (slightly modified to include an additional column, which is the rank value of 0) is loaded into the `HEADER` alias.

Next the actual data is loaded into the `H1` alias, as it grabs all files under the `header_test` directory.

`F_H1` filters out all headers from the data.  If you had 20 files that were loaded into `H1` from the `header_test` directory, those 20 headers would now be filtered out of the data.

`R_H1` creates a rank on the filtered data, in descending order and without skipping any numbers.

`U` effectively concatenates the ranked filtered data with the `0|column1|column2|column3` header line.

`O` orders the data by the rank, so that the header (which has a rank of 0), appears on top.

And finally, `F` gets rid of the ranking, leaving the clean tuples.

**Results**

```
(column1,column2,column3)
(60000,delhi,mike)
(30000,sydney,joseph)
(30000,sydney,joseph)
(20000,newyork,john)
```

### Method 2:

Basically, leave the headers on one file, strip them from the rest, and then mash them together.  Not sure it'll stay sorted, though, haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
H1 = LOAD 'header_test/header1.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (c1:chararray,c2:chararray,c3:chararray);
H2 = LOAD 'header_test/header2.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (d1:chararray,d2:chararray,d3:chararray);

F_H2 = FILTER H2 BY NOT (d1 MATCHES 'column1' AND d2 MATCHES 'column2' AND d3 MATCHES 'column3');

U = UNION H1, F_H2;
dump U;
```

**Results**

```
(column1,column2,column3)
(20000,newyork,john)
(30000,sydney,joseph)
(60000,delhi,mike)
(30000,sydney,joseph)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @jamCon  this works fine for merging of two different files it works fine,and provides mutiple output Part files(when data is in GBs, this is what my concern is i doesn't those as part files and to be in a single part and still i should make use of parlleling processing) actually my scenario is that i ran a MR job and output is having part files of which all are having headers because it having multiple reducers. i want those part files should written to a single large file of which having the top cloumn is header

Comment: If you ran Method 1 against your output directory (containing all of your part files) from the previous MR job, it would remove all of the headers from each part file, and then insert a pre-made header.

Comment: Another method you could potentially use would be to deduplicate the tuples.  That would get rid of the multiple identical headers.  I didn't suggest this as a Method initially, because you have a duplicate record in the two samples you provided (30000,sydney,joseph).

Comment: i agree this works fine and gives the output as i require, for which the PIG job will travesrse all the files and each row and checks wheather column name header is present are not ... (here the output will again be in parts as it is a map only job it gives as many parts as the count of mappers and again i need to merge them to single big file and here think in this way i just need to remove the 1st row of 2nd,3rd .. and nth file but we are traversing the entire 2nd,3rd ... and nth file inorder to remove those headers burdening the cpu )